# What is the structural difference between beta and gamma globin chains of Hb?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins

Hemoglobins are tetramers composed of pairs of two different polypeptide subunits. The subunit composition of the principal hemoglobins are α2β2 (HbA; normal adult hemoglobin), α2γ2 (HbF; fetal hemoglobin) and α2δ2 (HbA2; a minor adult hemoglobin)

The total number of amino acids in beta chain and gamma chain is the same-146. The higher affinity of HbF to oxygen is due to presence of serine(in gamma chain) in place of histidine(in beta chain), which inhibits its binding with 2,3-bisphosphoglyceric acid.

Is this the only difference, or are there more such differences in the amino acid sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [pairwise sequence alignment](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/psa/) of the human hemoglobin beta ([HBB](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P68871)) and gamma ([HBG1](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P69891)) chains:

```
HBB_HUMAN          1 VHLTPEEKSAVTALWGKVNVDEVGGEALGRLLVVYPWTQRFFESFGDLST     50
                     .|.|.|:|:.:|:|||||||::.|||.|||||||||||||||:|||:||:
HBG1_HUMAN         1 GHFTEEDKATITSLWGKVNVEDAGGETLGRLLVVYPWTQRFFDSFGNLSS     50

HBB_HUMAN         51 PDAVMGNPKVKAHGKKVLGAFSDGLAHLDNLKGTFATLSELHCDKLHVDP    100
                     ..|:||||||||||||||.:..|.:.|||:||||||.|||||||||||||
HBG1_HUMAN        51 ASAIMGNPKVKAHGKKVLTSLGDAIKHLDDLKGTFAQLSELHCDKLHVDP    100

HBB_HUMAN        101 ENFRLLGNVLVCVLAHHFGKEFTPPVQAAYQKVVAGVANALAHKYH    146
                     |||:|||||||.|||.||||||||.|||::||:|..||:||:.:||
HBG1_HUMAN       101 ENFKLLGNVLVTVLAIHFGKEFTPEVQASWQKMVTAVASALSSRYH    146
```

You can see the H143S (or S143H?) substitution, as well as many more.